# Is it possible to get a series of nested numbered lists without having a nested enumerate environment?

Tags: enumerate, nesting

In particular, I am hoping to accomplish something like your standard outline with text:

```
I. Level 1
II. Level 1
      A. Level 2
             1. Level 3
             2. Level 3
      B. Level 2
      C. Level 2
             1. Level 3
III. Level 1
```

Of course, normally this would require nested environments, i.e.,

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Level 1
  \item Level 1
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Level 2
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Level 3
      \item Level 3
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Level 2
    \item Level 2
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Level 3
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Level 1
\end{enumerate}
```

But I'm hoping to create a quasienumerate enviornment where the same thing can be accomplished by tagging levels to the item tags, e.g.,

```
\begin{quasienumerate}
  \itemlvlone Level 1
  \itemlvlone Level 1
  \itemlvltwo Level 2
  \itemlvlthree Level 3
  \itemlvlthree Level 3
  \itemlvltwo Level 2
  \itemlvltwo Level 2
  \itemlvlthree Level 3
  \itemlvlone Level 1
\end{quasienumerate}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You should expand your first example to a full, compilable MWE.

Comment: You might check out the outlines package.